# Login to AWS's ECR fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I get a timeout error when trying to login to AWS's ECR via Docker:

```
> $(aws --profile sly ecr get-login --region us-east-1)
```

Error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get <url>: dial tcp: lookup <url> on <ip>: read udp <addr>-><addr>: i/o timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had previously set my docker environment variables (DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH, etc.) to point to a Digital Ocean cloud instance.  Using docker-machine to switch to my local docker box fixed the issue:

```
> eval $(docker-machine env myLocalDockerHost)
> $(aws --profile sly ecr get-login --region us-east-1)
Login Succeeded
```

If anyone has certificate-related errors, this [AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223958) might be of help.